# Cannot activate bootstrap datapicker in MVC 5 Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm trying to activate the datapicker for a field but it's just not happening.

BundleConfig.cs:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/moment.js",
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
```

_Layout.html:

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Created a datepickerready.js in the *Scripts* folder:

```
$(function () {
$('.datetimepicker').datepicker();
```

});

And finally the *View* in which I want the datepicker to be available:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Achizitionare, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Achizitionare, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datetimepicker" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Achizitionare, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Found the solution: Forgot to call datepickerready.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: Forgot to call datepickerready.js